# Modal panel with asp.net being programmed with vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, postback, modal-dialog

I have an ajax modal panel with a div on it that I access from the server and dynamically insert a table into, by showing the values of various controls on the calling form.

My problem is this, it works fine if all my controls are doing auto postback, but it ruins the user experience, because tabbing through the controls, the controls lose focus during the automatic postback.

Is there a way to have my target control perform a postback, before it puts up the modal, so I can retrieve not posted controls data in the modal?  It still has to put up the modal.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the answer is no, but I don't understand the third paragraph - can you provide more details on the controls that appear in the DIV/table (and what sort of interaction they require). With more detail there may be another solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused. Do you mean a modal popup, or an AJAX `UpdatePanel`?

Either way, it sounds like your use case here may be more complex than out-of-the-box AJAX is able to handle. Your best bet may be a custom `ICallBackEventHandler` or `IPostBackEventHandler` operation.

Funnel all of your calls/postbacks through a single client-side function (JavaScript, et al.), grab necessary control state, send it to the server, and use the results to update your page. There are pretty decent examples in MSDN Library for all this. (See: [MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178208(VS.85).aspx))

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I believe I am aware of what you want to do.  You are trying to show and hide your modal popup via server side.  It actually is not that bad through a quick trick.  Create a hidden button that is bound to the modal.  In your code you can show and hide your modal once you bind to controls on your modal.

Please see the article below.  It should help you.  Happy coding!  Please let me know if this helps you.

http://lisazhou.wordpress.com/2007/12/27/ajaxnet-dynamically-load-data-in-modal-popup/